# Can I simply use the maven-publish Gradle plugin to upload to Bintray or do I HAVE to use the Bintray plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, bintray, maven-publish

I can publish artifacts using the JFrog Bintray Gradle plugin, but am getting a 405 when trying to use maven-publish plugin.

All the examples I've found use the JFrog plugin.

My Bintray repo is a Maven one and would like to stay with the generic maven plugin for uploads.

I noticed the JFrog plugin uses a repo url like `https://api.bintray.com/content/<USERNAME>/artifact-sandbox/`.

If I can use `maven-publish` should it use the same url?

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId 'samples'
            artifactId 'gradle-project'
            version '.1'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url = "<REPO-URL>"

            credentials {
                username = '<USERNAME>'
                password = '<BINTRAY-KEY>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try URL: https://api.bintray.com/maven/<USERNAME>/artifact-sandbox/;publish=1